# Как правильно просклонять: МОЕМУ СЫНУ или МОИМ СЫНОМ

Tags: склонение

Прошу обеспечить изучение родного русского языка и литературы (литературного чтения) моим сыном Ивановым Иваном Ивановичем.

Comment: Галина, не понимая ситуации, трудно рекомендовать Вам  какое-либо решение. Скажите: в школе, в которой учится Ваш сын, есть уроки русского языка и русской литературы у других школьников? в каком классе учится Ваш сын, изучал ли он русский в предыдущие годы? на каком языке ведётся обучение в школе? Почему возникла необходимость написания такого заявления? Кому оно будет адресовано?

Comment: Раздали в школе заявления, по поводу споров в пользу какого предмета отдать часы обучения.

Comment: Заявление. Прошу обеспечить изучение родного _____________ языка и литературы (литературного чтения) МОИМ СЫНОМ, _____________.

Comment: Мне показалось изначально не правильно написано это заявление, а именно не понятно как просклонять ФИО, и не понятно, будет ли предоставлено обучение МОЕМУ СЫНУ (его обучать будут) или МОИМ СЫНОМ (он обучать будет). Как то так))

Comment: Если уж такой бланк есть, то можно лишь обсудить, грамотно ли он составлен. Стиль, конечно, канцелярский, но все понятно и связно: обеспечить (что?) изучение, изучение (кем?) моим сыном, Ивановым Иваном Ивановичем. Язык будет изучаться сыном, то есть сын будет изучать язык.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написал немного иначе:

**Прошу предоставить [или обеспечить] моему сыну, Ивановy Иванy Ивановичy, возможность изучения родного (русского) языка и русской литературы (литературного чтения).**

Если от администрации требуется только разрешение — предоставить, если требуется произвести какие-то действия — обеспечить. "Родной русский язык" звучит как признание в любви к русскому языку, поэтому я добавил скобки. Есть еще варианты: "русского языка как (в качестве) родного", "русского языка, являющегося для него родным", "русского языка, поскольку он является для него родным" — все зависит от направленности Вашего письма.

Не обязательно придерживаться столь жесткого канцелярского стиля.
Еще варианты:

**Прошу предоставить [или обеспечить] моему сыну, Ивановy Иванy Ивановичy, возможность изучать родной (русский) язык и русскую литературу (литературное чтение).**

**Прошу создать необходимые условия для того, чтобы мой сын, Иванов Иван Иванович, мог изучать родной (русский) язык и русскую литературу (литературное чтение).**

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Пригодились.